# How to find ordinal position of any given weekday in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to find the actual position of a weekday in constant time. I get it working with loop but trying to find out it with some Mathematics. I know it is like divide it by 7 but not getting it work.

Here is the code.

```
for(var ind=0; ind<=between.length; ind++){
   if (new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek() === baseDtWk && new Date(between[ind]).getDay() === baseDtD) {
       datesToBeMarked.push(between[ind]);
       console.log(" :Date: " + between[ind] + " :Week: " + new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek());
       console.log("Date entered : " + new Date(between[ind]));
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the ordinal position of a weekday? You mean Sun = 0, Mon = 1, etc.?

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Comment: @Barmar `for(var ind=0; ind<=between.length; ind++){
   if (new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek() === baseDtWk && new Date(between[ind]).getDay() === baseDtD) {
       datesToBeMarked.push(between[ind]);
       console.log(" :Date: " + between[ind] + " :Week: " + new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek());
       console.log("Date entered : " + new Date(between[ind]));
   }

}`

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Your loop is operating on different dates in the `between` array, it's not determining the position of anything.

Comment: @Barmar initially I get range and then push that range in the between array. The magic is just finding the `week` of base date. And the `day` in `baseDtD`. Now by iterating over each element of an array. I check if this date has the same week and same day as the first date in this array. Then select it. It is working fine in happy scenario. The only problem is when the weekday is not in given week but in very next. How to reach at that very next occurrence of the weekday if not found in specified week?

Comment: @Barmar in short I can say that I want the very first occurrence of nth weekday in nth month in nth week. If not found find the first occurrence.

Comment: Now I'm really confused, because I don't see how the accepted answer does that.

Comment: @Barmar It is not doing exactly what I want according to my project requirements. But this snippet is way too useful than doing discussion and explaining to others whole day.

Comment: It seems to do the exact opposite of what you want. It takes a date and tells you where it is in the month, instead of taking a place in the month and telling you the date.

Comment: @Barmar `between[]` is an array of dates. Hence each element is representing a valid `date`.

Comment: I thought you were asking for a solution that doesn't require going through the whole array. Don't you need to call his `nthofMonth` function on every item in `between`?

Comment: @Barmar exactly I'm doing it. I know it is inefficient but I don't find any better answer yet.

Comment: You got it right. I'm checking each element and then recreating the date on that ordinal. It is lots of if and else and believe me it is very slow. I'm still looking for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this few days back. It is as simple as the code below. :)

[On fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LetMeCodeYou/zn12a55v/)

```
Number.prototype.nth= function(){
    var n= Math.round(this), t= Math.abs(n%100), i= t%10;
    if(i<4 && (t<4 || t> 20)){
        switch(i){
            case 1:return n+'st';
            case 2:return n+'nd';
            case 3:return n+'rd';
        }
    }
    return n+'th';
}
Date.prototype.nthofMonth= function(){
    var today= this.getDate(),m=this.getMonth(),
    day= ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
    'Friday', 'Saturday'][this.getDay()],
    month= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][m];
    return [(m+1)+'-'+today,'the ', Math.ceil(today/7).nth(), day, 'of', month, 'in', this.getFullYear()].join(' ');
}

var date=new Date().nthofMonth();
console.log(date);
```

Comment: `(Math.ceil((today)/7)).nth()` is much easier to read as `Math.ceil(today / 7).nth()`. Building an array just to format the output string is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you want the result to look, I guess you want to know if a particular date is, say, the nth Tuesday, e.g.

```
// Add ordinal to a number
function addOrdinal(n) {
    var ord = [,'st','nd','rd'];
    var a = n % 100;
    return n + (ord[a>20? a%10 : a] || 'th');
}

// Return the ordinal number of a day in the month
function ordinalDay(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
              'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday'];
  return addOrdinal(Math.ceil(d.getDate()/7)) + ' ' + days[d.getDay()];
}

console.log(ordinalDay(new Date(2015,0,1)));   // 1st Thursday
console.log(ordinalDay(new Date(2015,0,27)));  // 4th Tuesday
console.log(ordinalDay(new Date(2015,0,31)));  // 5th Saturday
console.log(ordinalDay(new Date(2015,11,25))); // 4th Friday
```

Comment: If I rephrase a bit to explain my original problem then I can say that `between[]` is an array which contains all the dates falls between a range given by the user. In this array's first element is my base to find out the same weekday. For instance if somehow I don't find the weekday in the same week as the first element's than there is an issue. How could I find it within my array, the first occurrence of that weekday? e.g 3rd of Mar is a Tuesday in the 1st week. But there is no Tuesday in first week of April. There is a Tuesday in 2nd week of April with the date 7. How can I reach there?

Comment: So based on the first date in the range, you want the corresponding nth ordinal week day for each month? E.g. if the first date is the 2nd Monday of the month, get the second Monday for each month in the range?

Comment: Yeah based on the first element of the array. Same weekday in same week. If first than first. If it is in third than third. Or if it is in the first but in the next month there is no weekday in the first week than go for the very first occurrence of this weekday. 

And same for the last week of nth month. If it is not in the last week than look in the second last week. I'm so pissed off by this problem. :(

Comment: Any ideas which can help me to my way?